# Zuul Routing not redirect to given URL after security filter get applied

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application which uses spring security and spring zuul routing and filters.I have 2 request one is /auth ,which is givens as ignored for security .Another one is /api , which uses a custom filter for JWT Authentication.
Current issue is that the second request /api  is not routed to the corresponsing service mentioned in the property file.

This is my security configuration class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigurtion extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationEntryPoinit customAuthEntrypoint;

    @Autowired
    private JwtConfig jwtConfig;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

         http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthEntrypoint)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
        .and()
        .antMatcher("/api/**") // if we mention the antmatcher first , it will apply only if the url starts with /api
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter jwtTokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(jwtConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean registration(JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registration.setEnabled(false);
        return registration;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/auth/**");//ignore all /auth request , so no security will be applied , so it wont check for matching filters for  /auth
    }
```

Routing proeprties

```
zuul.routes.auth-service.path=/auth/**
zuul.routes.auth-service.url=http://localhost:9100/
zuul.routes.auth-service.strip-prefix=false
zuul.routes.userservice.path=/api/userservice/**
zuul.routes.userservice.url=http://localhost:9200/
zuul.routes.userservice.strip-prefix=false
```

Please see the custom JWTAuthFilter

```
    package com.cavion.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;


public class JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final JwtConfig jwtConfig;

    public JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(JwtConfig jwtConfig) {
        this.jwtConfig = jwtConfig;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // 1. get the authentication header. Tokens are supposed to be passed in the
        // authentication header
        System.out.println("am in JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter");
        String header = request.getHeader(jwtConfig.getHeader());

        // 2. validate the header and check the prefix
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(jwtConfig.getPrefix())) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response); // If not valid, go to the next filter.
            return;
        }

        // If there is no token provided and hence the user won't be authenticated.
        // It's Ok. Maybe the user accessing a public path or asking for a token.

        // All secured paths that needs a token are already defined and secured in
        // config class.
        // And If user tried to access without access token, then he won't be
        // authenticated and an exception will be thrown.

        // 3. Get the token
        String token = header.replace(jwtConfig.getPrefix(), "");

        try { // exceptions might be thrown in creating the claims if for example the token is
                // expired

            // 4. Validate the token
            Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtConfig.getSecret().getBytes()).parseClaimsJws(token)
                    .getBody();

            String username = claims.getSubject();
            if (username != null) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<String> authorities = (List<String>) claims.get("authorities");

                // 5. Create auth object
                // UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken: A built-in object, used by spring to
                // represent the current authenticated / being authenticated user.
                // It needs a list of authorities, which has type of GrantedAuthority interface,
                // where SimpleGrantedAuthority is an implementation of that interface
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null,
                        authorities.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));

                // 6. Authenticate the user
                // Now, user is authenticated
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // In case of failure. Make sure it's clear; so guarantee user won't be
            // authenticated
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        }

        // go to the next filter in the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I have tried by passing correct bearer token also, but no change.

Please see the logs

```
    2019-02-01 22:28:12.356 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames'; against '/auth/**'
2019-02-01 22:28:12.356 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames'; against '/api/**'
2019-02-01 22:28:12.356 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2019-02-01 22:28:12.356 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2019-02-01 22:28:12.356 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2019-02-01 22:28:12.356 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2019-02-01 22:28:12.356 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2019-02-01 22:28:12.356 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames' doesn't match 'GET /logout
2019-02-01 22:28:12.356 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2019-02-01 22:28:12.356 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames'; against '/logout'
2019-02-01 22:28:12.356 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2019-02-01 22:28:12.356 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2019-02-01 22:28:12.356 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2019-02-01 22:28:12.356 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2019-02-01 22:28:12.356 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2019-02-01 22:28:12.356 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter'
am in JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter
2019-02-01 22:28:12.467 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2019-02-01 22:28:12.467 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2019-02-01 22:28:12.467 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2019-02-01 22:28:12.467 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7da74079: Principal: demo; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_user, admin'
2019-02-01 22:28:12.467 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2019-02-01 22:28:12.467 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@63d25458
2019-02-01 22:28:12.470 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2019-02-01 22:28:12.470 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2019-02-01 22:28:12.470 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames'; against '/api/**'
2019-02-01 22:28:12.470 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames; Attributes: [permitAll]
2019-02-01 22:28:12.470 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7da74079: Principal: demo; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_user, admin
2019-02-01 22:28:12.470 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@4d26c5a9, returned: 1
2019-02-01 22:28:12.470 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2019-02-01 22:28:12.470 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2019-02-01 22:28:12.470 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2019-02-01 22:28:12.472  INFO 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] com.cavion.filter.LoggerFilter           : POST request to http://localhost:8084/api/userservice/hostdata/gethostnames
2019-02-01 22:28:12.492 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] **o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@3c41ee75**
2019-02-01 22:28:12.495 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2019-02-01 22:28:12.495 DEBUG 8456 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Could anyone please look into it and help me to fix the routing issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that `/api/**` is permit all, and that is not what you want. After all, you wanted token authentication for JWT

`.antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()`

```java
       .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
        .and()
        .antMatcher("/api/**") // if we mention the antmatcher first , it will apply only if the url starts with /api
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
```

Spring Security works in two phases

1. Authentication - prove that you are who you say you are!
2. Authorization - are you allowed to do what you're about to do? Also known as access control

Let's take a look at a sample security filter (pseudo code removed any excess methods)

```java
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().denyAll()
        .httpBasic()
        .formLogin()
        .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
```

This filter will accept any of three different authentication methods

1. http-basic - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617
2. OAuth2 tokens(using JWT) - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749
3. form login (HTTP POST with body)

These configurations each insert a filter. That filter will *auto detect* if credentials are part of the request and perform authentication only if there are credentials.

The most important thing to understand that **if there are no credentials** as part of the incoming request, the filter will do nothing (no access control) and the filter chain continues.

Once Spring Security has run through all the *authentication* filters, it's time for authorization, or access control. Does this request have permissions to invoke this URL?

1. **Endpoint requires authentication**

`.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()`

This tells Spring Security that as long as the request is authenticated you can invoke anything that starts with */api*.
*It doesn't care where the authentication comes from. It could be basic, it could be form login or it could be a bearer token.*
This last statement is very important to understand. If you have multiple authentication methods in your filter chain, any of them will work.

2. **Endpoint does not require authentication**

`.antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()`

If an endpoint is *open*, then we use permitAll. Here we tell Spring Security that these endpoints can be accessed with or WITHOUT authentication.

If I place two matchers on the same path, like in the question

```
.antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
```

Spring Security will run through them in order, and use the first hit.
In this case, `permitAll` returns true, access granted. There is no need to check any other authorization configurations.

**So how should it be?**
My understanding is that you want `/api/**` be protected. And you don't care what *groups, roles or scopes* the user has. As long as the user is authenticated the `/api/**` endpoints can be accessed. In that case, you want to have

```
.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
```

and you do not want to use `permitAll`

Comment: So what’s your suggested fix for this ?

Comment: Should it be permit all or authenticated? You’re defining both and the first one wins￼

Comment: if my understanding is correct , the permitAll() will skip the authorization check only , all other filters will get applied

Comment: hi Ansar, let me update the answer. I think I understand where the confusion comes from.

Comment: @Flip : Thanks for the details explanation , now got the clear idea about the permitAall() , thats for correcting me.